# Stuck at finance "sell" !! really need some help here

Tags: python-3.x, cs50

If been stuck at this last checkpoint "sell" for ages... Meanwhile I've finished all the other sets and still don't see why the error appears.. the code works like it should work..

I assume it's a rounding issue but I cannot seem to find where or what to change.. pls really need some help here

the code bellow is the HTML jinja code that corresponds with the pythons script further down.. underneath runs a sqlite database... the error given by cs50 states ':( sell handles valid sale, cause expected to find "56.00" in page but it wasn't found'

```
    {% extends "layout.html" %}
    
    {% block title %}
         Sell
    {% endblock %}
    
    {% block main %}
    
        <form action="/sell" method="post">
    
            <div class="form-group">
                <select name = "symbol">
                    {% for symbol in my_symbols %}
    
                    <option>{{ symbol['symbol'] }}</option>
    
                    {% endfor %}
                </select>
    
            </div>
    
            <div class="form-group">
                <input class="form-control" name="shares" placeholder="Shares" type="number">
            </div>
    
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Sell</button>
        </form>
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    {% endblock %}
```

```
    {% extends "layout.html" %}
    
    {% block title %}
         Index
    {% endblock %}
    
    {% block main %}
    
    
    
    
       <table class ='table table-striped'> <!-- table -->
            <thead> <!-- table head-->
                <tr> <!-- table row-->
                    <th>Symbol</th> <!-- table heading-->
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Shares</th> <!-- table heading-->
                    <th>Price</th> <!-- table heading-->
                    <th>TOTAL</th>
                </tr> <!-- table row-->
            </thead> <!-- table head-->
    
    
             <tbody>
                 {% for item in sum_of_share %}
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ item['symbol'] }}</td>
    
                    <td>{{ item['name'] }}</td>
    
                    <td>{{ item['SUM(shares)'] }}</td>
    
                    <td>{{ usd(item['price']) }}</td>
    
                    <td>{{ usd(item['price'] * item['SUM(shares)']) }}</td>
                </tr>
                 {% endfor %}
                 <tr>
                    <td>CASH</td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>{{ usd(cash) }}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
    
            <tfoot>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td>{{ usd(total) }}</td>
            </tfoot>
        </table>
    
    
    {% endblock %}
```

```
    import os
    
    from cs50 import SQL
    from flask import Flask, flash, redirect, render_template, request, session
    from flask_session import Session
    from tempfile import mkdtemp
    from werkzeug.exceptions import default_exceptions, HTTPException, InternalServerError
    from werkzeug.security import check_password_hash, generate_password_hash
    
    from helpers import apology, login_required, lookup, usd
    
    # Configure application
    app = Flask(__name__)
    
    # Ensure templates are auto-reloaded
    app.config["TEMPLATES_AUTO_RELOAD"] = True
    
    
    # Ensure responses aren't cached
    @app.after_request
    def after_request(response):
        response.headers["Cache-Control"] = "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
        response.headers["Expires"] = 0
        response.headers["Pragma"] = "no-cache"
        return response
    
    
    # Custom filter
    app.jinja_env.filters["usd"] = usd
    
    # Configure session to use filesystem (instead of signed cookies)
    app.config["SESSION_FILE_DIR"] = mkdtemp()
    app.config["SESSION_PERMANENT"] = False
    app.config["SESSION_TYPE"] = "filesystem"
    Session(app)
    
    # Configure CS50 Library to use SQLite database
    db = SQL("sqlite:///finance.db")
    
    # Make sure API key is set
    if not os.environ.get("API_KEY"):
        raise RuntimeError("API_KEY not set")
    
    
    @app.route("/")
    @login_required
    def index():
        user_id = session["user_id"]
    
        sum_of_share = db.execute("SELECT symbol, name, price, SUM(shares) FROM transactions WHERE user_id = ? GROUP BY symbol ORDER BY time DESC;", user_id)
        cash = db.execute("SELECT cash from users where id = ?", user_id)[0]['cash']
        total = cash
    
        for i in sum_of_share:
            total += int(sum_of_share[0]['price']) * int(sum_of_share[0]['SUM(shares)'])
    
    
        return render_template("index.html", sum_of_share=sum_of_share, cash=cash, total=total, usd=usd) #sum_of_share=sum_of_share)
    
    
    
    
    
    
    @app.route("/history")
    @login_required
    def history():
        user_id = session["user_id"]
    
        history = db.execute("SELECT * FROM transactions WHERE user_id = ? ORDER BY time DESC;", user_id)
        cash_history = db.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ?;", user_id)
        return render_template("history.html", history=history, cash_history=cash_history, usd=usd )
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    @app.route("/register", methods=["GET", "POST"])
    def register():
    
        # User reached route via POST (as by submitting a form via POST)
        if request.method == "POST":
    
            # Ensure username was submitted
            if not request.form.get("username"):
                return apology("must provide username", 400)
    
            # Ensure password was submitted
            elif not request.form.get("password"):
                return apology("must provide password", 400)
    
            elif not request.form.get("confirmation", 400):
                return apology("must check password")
    
            elif request.form.get("password") != request.form.get("confirmation"):
                return apology("passwords do not match", 400)
    
    
            # Query database for username
            rows = db.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?", request.form.get("username"))
    
            # Ensure username does not exists in the database yet
            if len(rows) >= 1:
                return apology("username already exists", 400)
    
            #hashes password
            password = generate_password_hash(request.form.get("password"))
    
            #inserts to db
            db.execute("INSERT INTO users (username, hash, confirmation) VALUES(?, ?, ?)", request.form.get("username"), password, "check" ) # inserts the data from the submitting html page into the sql database..
            # Redirect user to home page
            return redirect("/login")
    
        # User reached route via GET (as by clicking a link or via redirect)
        else:
            return render_template("register.html")
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    @app.route("/login", methods=["GET", "POST"])
    def login():
        """Log user in"""
    
        # Forget any user_id
        session.clear()
    
        # User reached route via POST (as by submitting a form via POST)
        if request.method == "POST":
    
            # Ensure username was submitted
            if not request.form.get("username"):
                return apology("must provide username", 400)
    
            # Ensure password was submitted
            elif not request.form.get("password"):
                return apology("must provide password", 400)
    
            # Query database for username
            rows = db.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?", request.form.get("username"))
    
            # Ensure username exists and password is correct
            if len(rows) != 1 or not check_password_hash(rows[0]["hash"], request.form.get("password")):
                return apology("invalid username and/or password", 400)
    
            # Remember which user has logged in
            session["user_id"] = rows[0]["id"]
    
            user_id = session["user_id"]
    
            # rows = db.execute("SELECT * FROM user_data WHERE logged_user = ?", user_id)
    
            # Ensure username does not exists in the database yet
            # if len(rows) >= 1:
            #     return redirect("/")
            # else:
            #     db.execute("INSERT INTO user_data (symbol, total_stock_v, shares, cash_v, current_stock_v, logged_user) VALUES('NULL', 0.0, 0.0, 10000.0, 0.0, ?)", user_id)
    
            return redirect("/")
            # Redirect user to home page
    
    
        # User reached route via GET (as by clicking a link or via redirect)
        else:
            return render_template("login.html")
    
    
    @app.route("/logout")
    def logout():
        """Log user out"""
    
        # Forget any user_id
        session.clear()
    
        # Redirect user to login form
        return redirect("/")
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    @app.route("/quote", methods=["GET", "POST"])
    @login_required
    def quote():
    
        if request.method == "POST":
    
            # Ensure username was submitted
            if not request.form.get("symbol"):
                return apology("must provide a symbol", 400)
    
            symbol = request.form.get("symbol")
            quote = lookup(symbol)
            if quote == None:
                return apology("symbol not in database")
    
            name = quote["name"]
            product = quote["symbol"]
            price = usd(quote["price"])
    
            stock = "A share of {0}. {1}, costs {2}".format(name, product, price)
    
            return render_template("quote.html", stock=stock)
    
        # User reached route via GET (as by clicking a link or via redirect)
        else:
            return render_template("quote.html")
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    @app.route("/buy", methods=["GET", "POST"])
    @login_required
    def buy():
        """Buy shares of stock"""
    
        if request.method == "POST":
    
            symbol = request.form.get("symbol").upper()
            quote = lookup(symbol)
    
            # Ensure username was submitted
            if not symbol:
                return apology("must provide a symbol", 400)
    
            elif quote == None:
                return apology("symbol not in database", 400)
    
    
    
            try:
                share = int(request.form.get("shares"))
            except ValueError:
                return apology("must provide a number", 400)
    
            if not share:
                return apology("must provide a share", 400)
            elif share <= 0:
                return apology("must provide a positive amount", 400)
    
            user_id = session["user_id"]
            cash_user = db.execute("SELECT cash FROM users WHERE id = ?", user_id)
            cash = cash_user[0]["cash"]
    
            stock_name = quote["name"]
            stock_price = quote["price"]
            total_price = stock_price * share
    
    
            if total_price > cash:
                return apology("not enough saldo", 400)
            else:
                cash = (cash - total_price)
                db.execute("UPDATE users SET cash = ? WHERE id = ?", cash, user_id)#WHERE username = ?);", request.form.get("username"))
    
                insert_data = "INSERT INTO transactions (user_id, name, shares, price, type, symbol) VALUES( ?, ? , ? , ?, ?, ?);" #ADD logged in time and user in db
                db.execute(insert_data, user_id, stock_name, share, stock_price, 'buy', symbol)
    
                return redirect("/")
    
    
        # User reached route via GET (as by clicking a link or via redirect)
        else:
            return render_template("buy.html")
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    @app.route("/sell", methods=["GET", "POST"])
    @login_required
    def sell():
        """ shares of stock"""
    
        if request.method == "POST":
            user_id = session["user_id"]
            symbol = request.form.get("symbol").upper()
            share = int(request.form.get("shares"))
            quote = lookup(symbol)
    
    
            # Ensure username was submitted
            if not symbol:
                return apology("must provide a symbol", 400)
    
            elif quote == None:
                return apology("symbol not in database", 400)
    
    
    
            try:
                share = int(request.form.get("shares"))
            except ValueError:
                return apology("must provide a number", 400)
    
    
            if not share:
                return apology("must provide a share", 400)
    
            elif share <= 0:
                return apology("must provide a positive amount", 400)
    
            user_id = session["user_id"]
            cash_user = db.execute("SELECT cash FROM users WHERE id = ?", user_id)
            cash = cash_user[0]["cash"]
    
            stock_price = usd(quote["price"])
            stock_name = quote["name"]
            total_price = stock_price * share
    
    
    
    
    
            rows = db.execute("SELECT * FROM transactions WHERE user_id = ?;", user_id)
            holdings = db.execute("SELECT symbol, SUM(shares) FROM transactions WHERE user_id = ? AND symbol = ? GROUP BY symbol", user_id, symbol)
            holding = holdings[0]['SUM(shares)']
    
            if len(rows) == 1:
                return apology("not enough holdings", 400)
    
    
            elif holding <  share:
                return apology("not enough holdings", 400)
    
            elif quote == None:
                return apology("symbol not in database", 400)
    
            elif total_price > cash:
                return apology("not enough saldo", 400)
    
    
            else:
                cash = cash + total_price
                share = (share - share) - share
                db.execute("UPDATE users SET cash = ? where id = ?", cash, user_id)
    
    
                insert_data = "INSERT INTO transactions (user_id, name, shares, price, type, symbol) VALUES( ?, ? , ? , ?, ?, ?);" #ADD logged in time and user in db
                db.execute(insert_data, user_id, stock_name, share, stock_price, 'sell', symbol)
    
    
                return redirect("/")
    
    
        # User reached route via GET (as by clicking a link or via redirect)
        else:
            user_id = session["user_id"]
            my_symbols = db.execute("SELECT DISTINCT(symbol) FROM transactions WHERE user_id = ?;", user_id)
            return render_template("sell.html", my_symbols=my_symbols)
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    def errorhandler(e):
        """Handle error"""
        if not isinstance(e, HTTPException):
            e = InternalServerError()
        return apology(e.name, e.code)
    
    
    # Listen for errors
    for code in default_exceptions:
        app.errorhandler(code)(errorhandler)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is hurting you:

```
if len(rows) == 1:
    return apology("not enough holdings", 400)
```

Register a new user; buy 4 shares of any stock; sell 2 shares. I would expect program to give "not enough holdings" message because the buy inserted one row into `transactions` table.